# Fail to replicate quarto elsevier template

Tags: r, rstudio, journal, quarto

I am currently trying to migrate from rmarkdown to quarto through rstudio platform. First step, I would like to create a scientific article based on elsevier template which could be found [Text](https://github.com/quarto-journals/elsevier). However, I failed to replicate it. When I tried to render the `template.qmd` there was a sudden warning sign `ERROR: No valid input files passed to render`.

I've looked at the format, strangely if I add an additonal line to it, it worked somehow.

Original code (NOT WORKING):

```
---
title: Short Paper
author:
  - name: Alice Anonymous
    email: alice@example.com
    affiliations: 
        - id: some-tech
          name: Some Institute of Technology
          department: Department Name
          address: Street Address
          city: City
          state: State
          postal-code: Postal Code
    attributes:
        corresponding: true
    note: This is the first author footnote.
  - name: Bob Security
    email: bob@example.com
    affiliations:
        - id: another-u
          name: Another University
          department: Department Name
          address: Street Address
          city: City
          state: State
          postal-code: Postal Code
    note: |
      Another author footnote, this is a very long footnote and it should be a really long footnote. But this footnote is not yet sufficiently long enough to make two lines of footnote text.
  - name: Cat Memes
    email: cat@example.com
    affiliations:
        - ref: another-u
    note: Yet another author footnote.
  - name: Derek Zoolander
    email: derek@example.com
    affilations:
        - ref: some-tech
abstract: |
  This is the abstract. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum augue turpis, dictum non malesuada a, volutpat eget velit. Nam placerat turpis purus, eu tristique ex tincidunt et. Mauris sed augue eget turpis ultrices tincidunt. Sed et mi in leo porta egestas. Aliquam non laoreet velit. Nunc quis ex vitae eros aliquet auctor nec ac libero. Duis laoreet sapien eu mi luctus, in bibendum leo molestie. Sed hendrerit diam diam, ac dapibus nisl volutpat vitae. Aliquam bibendum varius libero, eu efficitur justo rutrum at. Sed at tempus elit.
keywords: 
  - keyword1
  - keyword2
#journal: "An awesome journal"
date: last-modified
# bibliography: bibliography.bib
format:
  elsevier-pdf:
    keep-tex: true
    journal:
      formatting: preprint
      model: 3p
      cite-style: authoryear
```

Fixed code (WORKING but...)

```
---
title: Short Paper

format:
  pdf: default
  elsevier-pdf:
    keep-tex: true
---
```

by adding `pdf: default` before `elsevier-pdf`, the code worked, but I also lost all the footnotes and superscript code after each author. Is there any workaround on this?

Comment: I encounter a similar error when trying to render a qmd from a shared drive, when it renders fine on my documents folder. Please see this ticket on GitHub: https://www.github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/2380

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

1. Make sure your RStudio version is up to date (see https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/) and make sure required packages are installed.
2. Install quarto on your system (in my case: https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-quarto/#quarto-tar-file-install).
3. On the command line run `quarto use template quarto-journals/elsevier`:

[image]
and open the `quarto1.qmd` file with RStudio and render it. Alternatively, you could try to run `quarto install extension quarto-journals/elsevier` to install the extension.

Comment: I am following those step, but when I tried to run the ```quarto use template quarto-journals/elsevier``` it just resulted as empty folder...

Comment: @BramSetyadjiMadusuyatno, did your command led you to a dialogue as shown above? If so, you should see the created files listed, or maybe an error message (e.g. no write permissions). Also check if it managed to download the template (issues with internet connection, proxy...).